# 3D Slicer installation fails? It does not run as if it does not exist

Tags: software-installation

I installed Ubuntu 12 through windows installer. I tried to install 3D Slicer 4.3.1 software but it does not open, cannot be launched. What is going on?
www.slicer.org

Answer (score 0):

1- you need download 3DSlicer from web: http://download.slicer.org/ for linux 64bit (stable is recomended)

2- you need uncompress this file in your Desktop for example.

3- Open a terminal and tip:
   Desktop/Slicer-4.3.1-linux-amd64/Slicer

changin "4.3.1....." for the name of your folder uncompresed.

Now you will see a 3DSlicer runing!

Best

Comment: Nope. Personally I still get the `error: Failed to obtain launcher executable name !`